# Entity Framework 3 - Navigation Property Null with Varying Include()

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have a query method where I sometimes include additional tables "Category" and "Manufacturer" depending on the situation.  However, whenever I run the query, the category and manufacturer navigation properties are always blank.  What am I doing wrong?

```
private IQueryable<Item> GetQuery(ItemFilter filter, ItemCacheContainer context)
    {
        //Perform optional Joins
        ObjectQuery<Item> query = context.Items;

        if (filter.JoinCategory)
            query.Include("Category");

        if (filter.JoinManufacturer)
            query.Include("Manufacturer");

        return query.Where(i =>
              (!filter.ItemId.HasValue
              || i.ItemId == filter.ItemId.Value));
    }
```

Also, here's how I'm using the `GetQuery` method but when I put a breakpoint in `ConvertItemFromCache` I see those null navigation properties.

```
GetQuery(filter, context)
    .ToList()
    .ConvertAll(ConvertItemFromCache)
    .SingleOrDefault();
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set `query` to the result of `query.Include("...")`

```
query = query.Include("Category");
```

So in your example:

```
if (filter.JoinCategory)
 query = query.Include("Category");

if (filter.JoinManufacturer)
 query = query.Include("Manufacturer");
```

Comment: Please, can you add the same for *!filter.ItemId.HasValue*?

Comment: @AdrianIftode - He doesn't need to set query to that, because he is returning it from the method